# OAuth2 Refresh token scopes

Tags: oauth-2.0, refresh-token

I am implementing an OAuth2 server that supports refresh token however, there is something that I am not been able to understand fully.

When a user request for a new access token via the `refresh_token` `grant_type` and he/she requested lesser scope (3 out of the 5 scopes) than what the original access token has. Should the refresh token have the original scopes or should the refresh token have the new scopes requested?

- If the refresh token has the new scopes requested, does this mean that eventually, they will run out of scopes if they keep requesting lesser scopes?
- Should the refresh token keep the original scopes? This would mean that an access token returned would have different scopes as to what is stored in the refresh token, and the next request to get a new access token may result in more scopes than the current access token.

Can someone please enlighten me on this issue?

I have read the RFC docs and there is a point that states

> If a new refresh token is issued, the refresh token scope MUST be
>   identical to that of the refresh token included by the client in the
>   request.

Answer (score 0):

For a refresh token grant:

- The base behaviour is to receive only a new access token in the response
- The original refresh token is then reused a number of times.

Some authorization servers support refresh token rotation and may also:

- Issue a new 'rolling' refresh token
- This is bound to the original scopes and session time

At least that's the theory, though you need to test for your particular authorization server. Vendor support from the likes of Microsoft, AWS and others varies considerably.

Comment: Thanks. We are building our own auth server which requires refresh token rotation. I think keeping the original scopes is the right way to go since that's what the user originally allows the application to have access to.

Comment: What are the scopes that are missing? What if there are pages and or endpoints that require a different expiry time before a user needs to re-authenticate. For instance, one may want to be able to see a logged in homepage where they get their preferences, and their previous purchases. But, when it comes time to update or add a new address….. one may not want to rely on a longer living session. Or one may require authentication for every single update regardless of the last time they authenticated. Could that be the case here?